# Как решить систему из 4 уравнений с помощью Python?

Tags: python

Нужно найти решение системы: привести пример такой комбинации натуральных чисел r, b, y, p, чтобы выполнялась следующая система уравнений.

```
(r + b + y) = 12
(r + b + p) = 16
(r + y + p) = 14
(y + b + p) = 24
```

Известно, что такая комбинация одна.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: в натуральных числах комбинаций нет, а целых - есть и она одна

Comment: написал программу на питоне, посмотрел ответ и понял :) программу привел в комментарии :)

Comment: Dmitry - посмотрите мой ответ - я дописал как задача решается теоретически... за 1 минутку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

например так - почти в лоб, но побыстрее:

```
for r in range(-100, 100):
    for b in range(-100, 100):
        y = 12 - r - b
        p = 16 - r - b
        if r + y + p == 14 and y + b + p == 24:
            print(b, p, r, y)
```

А вообще задача решается на бумаге так:

1. складываем все уравнения и получаем

   ```
    (r + b + y) + (r + b + p) + (r + y + p) + (y + b + p) = 12 + 16 + 14 + 24
    3r + 3b + 3p + 3y = 66
    r + b + p + y = 22
   ```
2. дальше вычитаем из полученного уравнения все уравнения и получаем переменные:

   ```
    (r + b + p + y) - (r + b + y) = 22 - 12
    p = 10

    (r + b + p + y) - (r + b + p) = 22 - 16
    y = 6

    (r + b + p + y) - (r + y + p) = 22 - 14
    b = 8

    (r + b + p + y) - (y + b + p) = 22 - 24
    r = -2
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Если переписать ваши у уравнения в каноническом для линейной алгебры виде, например так:

```
(r + b +     y) = 12    
(r + b + p    ) = 16    
(r     + p + y) = 14    
(    b + p + y) = 24
```

То получим обычную систему линейных уравнений 4 на 4, :

1  1  0  1      12
1  1  1  0      16
1  0  1  1      14
0  1  1  1      24
которая, как известно из линейной алгебры, имеет не более одного решения.

Для решения линейных уравнений есть модуль scipy:

```
from scipy.linalg import solve
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
          [1,  1,  0,  1, ],
          [1,  1,  1,  0, ],
          [1,  0,  1,  1, ],
          [0,  1,  1,  1, ]
    ])
b = np.array([12, 16, 14, 24])
x = solve(a, b)
print(x)
```

дает результат:

```
[-2.  8. 10.  6.]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for r in range(-10, 21):
    for b in range(-10, 21):
        for y in range(-10, 21):
            for p in range(-10, 21):
                if (r + b + y == 12) and (r + b + p == 16) and\
                    (r + y + p == 14) and (y + b + p == 24):
                    print(f"r = {r} \nb = {b} \ny = {y} \np = {p}")
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: O(n^4), хотя тут O(n^2) можно обойтись

Comment: Не понял тебя. o(n^4) o(n^2) - что это?

Comment: сложность алгоритма - у вас 4 вложенных `for` , а значит кол-во операций будет в вашем случае (21 - (-10))^4 = 923521 цикла, а можно сделать задачу только через 2 вложенных цикла `for` и тогда будет 961 операция

если решение было бы скажем 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 - то вы замучались бы решать вашим способом

Comment: Это да, но задача состоит не в универсальности решения, а в его результате. Данная задача не содержит больших чисел, поэтому можно обойтись таким способом, при котором даже думать не надо, как писать.

Comment: @Zhihar Решение с перебором, конечно, не оптимальное, но в Google Colab работает за 0.1 секунду, этого вполне достаточно )